# HP B110i controller not seeing storage array. Any ideas?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas, hp-smart-array

We got a new HP ProLiant DL160G6 with internal P410 SAS controller, and an additional B110i SAS controller with external ports that is supposed to connect to the HP Storageworks D2600 Drive Array we got too.

The B110i has the battery installed, but no cache module. We switched the SATA mode in BIOS to RAID, like the manual said.

Now, when I boot the server, during boot it sees the P410, which recognizes the two internal drives, then next it sees the B110i, but that claims to have detected no physical devices, and gives me no options to enter into ORCA or CLI config, unlike the P410.

We've tried three SAS cables, and all ports, both on the controller and the array ends, to no effect. Not even the little green light next to the port on the array is lighting up.

We're pretty much at our wits' end. Anyone got any ideas on how to activate the B110i we might have missed before we send the unit back for repair?

Edit:
Thank you very much ewwhite and Chopper3 for your help. After checking the delivery dockets we found that we were supposed to get a P411 in the first place. They put the wrong card in.
Someone's gonna get an angry phone call tomorrow morning...

Comment: Something's not right here. The B110i is a Motherboard Integrated controller (the "i" on the end hints that). The P410 is a PCIe card with 1 internal SATA connection and 0 external (hence the x10 model number); it doesn't support SAS either. With those in the server there would be no external connections for the D2600. Changing modes in BIOS for the B110i would have no effect on whatever you've got going externally. Do you have HP's ACU installed?

Comment: If you have a P410 installed and detecting internal drives then you must have the SAS backplane internally. If you have the D2600 plugged into something you must have a P411 (or similar) card installed. Check out HP's ACU software and see what it has to say about controllers and drives.

Answer (score 1):

This combination is not compatible. Yell at the people who sold you the equipment...

From the second paragraph of the [HP Quickspecs for the D2600](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13404_na/13404_na.html),

```
The D2000 enclosures support direct attach storage to ProLiant Servers with the HP Smart Array P411, P212 and the P812 Controllers.
```

Comment: It's not compatible because there'd be no way to plug an external drive array (D2600) into internal-only cards (P410 and B110i <- Which is also a SATA card, not SAS).

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because, the B110i controller is a SATA controller and not a SAS controller as mentioned in the original query.

It does not support the SAS hard drives, but, only the SATA hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

The D2600 doesn't support being ran from a B110i sorry, should have checked the [quickspecs](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13404_na/13404_na.PDF).

Get it swapped out for a P212, P411 or P812 instead.

Comment: There's no way to plug a D2600 into the on-board B110i SATA controller anyway... Not without some 3rd party bracket installed in the server.

Comment: Hmmm okay... if the B110i is onboard (which I didn't know) then the card installed must be the P411 that was ordered, and it's simply not being seen. Because all that is shown during boot is the P410 and the B110i. Well, either way, gotta get the folks in who sold it to us tomorrow, either the second PCIe-Card is broken OR the wrong part. Thank you Chris S