# HP P411 Storage Controller not recognized during boot

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sas

it's me again :( I've asked a question here a few minutes ago ( [HP B110i controller not seeing storage array. Any ideas?](https://serverfault.com/questions/346593/hp-b110i-controller-not-seeing-storage-array-any-ideas) )

Turns out I was wrong, and there IS a P411 controller built in, I verified by opening up the server.

The problem has changed somewhat now. The server/BIOS is seeing the built in P410 and the onboard B110i (I get the 'Initializing' messages for both, and get the option to enter ORCA or CLI setup for the P410, but it's not seeing the P411.

The manual claims the server would self-configure, and I couldn't find any further options in BIOS or elsewhere.

Sorry for having to ask again, but any ideas how to activate the P411? I checked the status LEDs on the controller, and only the "Port 2 active" LED is on, steady light, irrespective of if there's a SAS cable connected and to which of the two ports, and the port light on the D2600 isn't lighting up.

Any ideas?

P.S.: The SAS cables have a diamond on one connector and a circle on the other. Does this have any significance? I couldn't find any reference to this. I tried it both ways around, didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the cables, if the machine's not being seen on boot then there's something very wrong. Try changing the slot the card's in, if that doesn't work flag it as dead on arrival and get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [calling HP support](http://h20230.www2.hp.com/contact_list.jsp?print=1) in this case to troubleshoot or arrange for a replacement controller. You can also contact the vendor. To clarify, a Smart Array P410 is an internal-only controller. The Smart Array P411 has external ports on the PCIe card faceplace in order to interface with external storage units.

Comment: Jup. Our Machine has one of each in, and it's the P411 that's not being seen.

Comment: Did this answer your question?